# LIKE query not working properly in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to search from Custom Post Type but it's not working properly. When I print the query, it returned me the below query.

Note : I've searched for **Dundee**

```
wp_postmeta.meta_value LIKE '{8c5188211f021bf38618811f0d14f1bc5cd92d1e3f431bead36b3f403190aba3}Dundee{8c5188211f021bf38618811f0d14f1bc5cd92d1e3f431bead36b3f403190aba3}'
```

Below is my query.

```
$search = [];
if(isset($_POST['location']) && $_POST['location']!==""){
        array_push($search,array('key'=>'property_address','value'=>$_POST['location'],'compare' => 'LIKE'));
}
$args = array('post_type' => 'property','post_status' => 'publish', 'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        $search
));
$loop = new WP_Query($args);
wp_send_json_success( $loop->request);die();
```

Comment: you should replace `$` symbols with `jQuery` in wordpress and pass the `$` into the function, for example `jQuery(document).ready(function($) {  #code  });` hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

I has a similar situation. The {} values appear to be % characters encoded. In my case, the search term i was looking for just didnt exist...double check your database and expected results for Dundee.
Try this code also:

```
    $search;
    if(isset($_POST['location']) && $_POST['location']!==""){
        $search=array(
            'key'=>'property_address',
            'value'=>$_POST['location'],
            'compare' => 'LIKE'));
    }

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'property',
        'post_status' => 'publish', 
        'meta_query' => $search,
    );
```